# How does Relay / GraphQL 'resolve' works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I am trying out [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) and [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/). When I am doing the schema I am doing this:

```
let articleQLO = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Article',
  description: 'An article',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: globalIdField('Article'),
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The title of the article',
      resolve: (article) => article.getTitle(),
    },
    author: {
      type: userConnection,
      description: 'The author of the article',
      resolve: (article) => article.getAuthor(),
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
})
```

So, when I ask for an article like this:

```
{
  article(id: 1) {
    id,
    title,
    author
  }
}
```

Will it do 3 queries to the database? I mean, each field has a resolve method (`getTitle`, `getAuthor`, etc.) which does a request to the database. Am I doing this wrong?

This is an example of `getAuthor` (I use mongoose):

```
articleSchema.methods.getAuthor = function(id){
  let article = this.model('Article').findOne({_id: id})
  return article.author
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `resolve` method is passed the `article`, can't you just access the property?

```
let articleQLO = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Article',
  description: 'An article',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: globalIdField('Article'),
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The title of the article',
      resolve: (article) => article.title,
    },
    author: {
      type: userConnection,
      description: 'The author of the article',
      resolve: (article) => article.author,
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
})
```

Since `Schema.methods` in Mongoose defines methods *on the model*, it wouldn't take an ID for the article (because you call it on an article instance). So, if you wanted to keep the method, you would just do:

```
articleSchema.methods.getAuthor = function() {
  return article.author;
}
```

If it was something you need to look up e.g. in another collection, *then* you'd need to do a separate query (assuming you're not using refs):

```
articleSchema.methods.getAuthor = function(callback) {
  return this.model('Author').find({ _id: this.author_id }, cb);
}
```